# SharePoint Calendar Calculate Number of Days (hours) Off

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-online

I have a calendar on SharePoint online that I'm trying to use to track the amount of leave time employees use. Currently I'm capturing the number of hours daily that the employees are using a field on the event, but I would like to calculate the number of workdays in each event so that I can find out the total number of hours used by a given person.

I already assume I'm going to need another field to capture this, but how would I perform the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below formula used to calculate working days, hope this helps.

```
=(DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"D"))-INT(DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"D")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY([Due Date])-WEEKDAY([Start Date]))<0,2,0)+1
```

Comment: Why is the +1 at the end of this statement? In my tests this is creating an error with the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

To get the working days from event item between the 'from' and 'to' columns You can use the following formula:

```
    =IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(From,To,"d")),"",(DATEDIF(From,To,"d"))+1-INT(DATEDIF(From,To,"d")/7)*2-IF((WEEKDAY(To)-WEEKDAY(From))0),1,0)-IF(AND(NOT(WEEKDAY(From)=7),WEEKDAY(To)=7),1,0))
```